# How to remove XUL item from toolbar programatically

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I have a Firefox extension that adds several buttons to the "nav-bar" toolbar using recommended technique (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Toolbar#Adding_button_by_default). Everything works fine, buttons are added on first start, users are able to add, remove or reorganise the buttons.

I need to be able to add and remove these buttons via custom dialog. And here's the problem: I can add buttons via `insertItem` method, but there is no `removeItem` method.

I can remove the item by calling `removeChild` DOM method and then removing the item ID from toolbar's `currentset` attribute. But then I can't reenable the item before restarting the browser, because it doesn't return to the palette.

```js
// remove item's ID from toolbar's current set of items
// this does not remove the item
toolbar.setAttribute('currentset', newSet);
document.persist(toolbar.id, 'currentset');

// item is removed, but it doesn't return to palette
// so it can't be added againg before restart
toolbar.removeChild(button);
```

Is there any way I can not only add, but also remove items from Firefox toolbars programatically? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you just update the `"currentSet"` property and don't call `removeChild`?  That should move the button to the palette I think.

Comment: Correct, only that the `toolbar.currentSet` property should be changed instead of the attribute (the property will update the attribute among other things).